# Replace string at index in a particular row of a list/dataframe with a string from row at the same index

Tags: python, list, loops, replace, iterator

I have a 2d array like this one:

```
list_of_data = 
    [['Joe', 4, 'MSP', 4, 5, 'cabbage', None], 
    ['Joe', 43, '2TM', 41, 53, 'cabbage', None],
    ['Joe', 24, 'MSP', 44, 55, 'cabbage', None],
    ['Joe', 54, 'MIA', 42, 85, 'cabbage', None],

    ['Tom', 7, '2TM', 4, 52, 'cabbage', None],
    ['Tom', 4, 'LAX', 43, 52, 'cabbage', None],
    ['Tom', 4, 'MCO', 4, 5, 'cabbage', None],

    ['Fred', 4, '2TM', 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
    ['Fred', 4, 'LAG', 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
    ['Fred', 4, 'ITH', 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage']]
```

This question is about the rows/indexes containing the value '2TM' at its 2nd index. For example:

Joe has the value '2TM' at index 2 in the 2nd appearance of his data.
Tom has the value '2TM' at index 2 in the 1st appearance of his data.
Fred has the value '2TM' at index 2 in the 1st appearance of his data.

Each time the value '2TM' appears in the data, I want to replace '2TM' with the values at the same index in the next two rows, separated by a hyphen. The example above would become the following:

```
list_of_data = 
    [['Joe', 4, 'MSP', 4, 5, 'cabbage', None], 
    ['Joe', 43, 'MSP-MIA', 41, 53, 'cabbage', None],
    ['Joe', 24, 'MSP', 44, 55, 'cabbage', None],
    ['Joe', 54, 'MIA', 42, 85, 'cabbage', None],

    ['Tom', 7, 'LAX-MCO', 4, 52, 'cabbage', None],
    ['Tom', 4, 'LAX', 43, 52, 'cabbage', None],
    ['Tom', 4, 'MCO', 4, 5, 'cabbage', None],

    ['Fred', 4, 'LAG-ITH', 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
    ['Fred', 4, 'LAG', 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
    ['Fred', 4, 'ITH', 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage']]
```

I've tried using the replace. method to get what might be close to the right code:

```
x=0
for row in list_of_data:
    if '2TM' in row:
        list_of_data.replace(list_of_data[2], list_of_data[x+1 + x+2])
    x+=1
```

This yields the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: You mention dataframe. So, you're open to a pandas solution?

Comment: I think the last snippet isn't properly indented.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Actually, yes, I'm very open to a pandas solution too.

Comment: @SamChats Sorry, I fixed this. The snippet was originally indented as shown now, but it moved as I was pasting it here for my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do:

```
list_of_data = [['Joe', 4, 'MSP', 4, 5, 'cabbage', None],
                ['Joe', 43, '2TM', 41, 53, 'cabbage', None],
                ['Joe', 24, 'MSP', 44, 55, 'cabbage', None],
                ['Joe', 54, 'MIA', 42, 85, 'cabbage', None],

                ['Tom', 7, '2TM', 4, 52, 'cabbage', None],
                ['Tom', 4, 'LAX', 43, 52, 'cabbage', None],
                ['Tom', 4, 'MCO', 4, 5, 'cabbage', None],

                ['Fred', 4, '2TM', 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
                ['Fred', 4, 'LAG', 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
                ['Fred', 4, 'ITH', 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage']]

for i in range(len(list_of_data)):
    if list_of_data[i][2] == '2TM':
        list_of_data[i][2] = list_of_data[i+1][2] + '-' + list_of_data[i+2][2]

print(list_of_data)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[['Joe', 4, 'MSP', 4, 5, 'cabbage', None], ['Joe', 43, 'MSP-MIA', 41, 53, 'cabbage', None], ['Joe', 24, 'MSP', 44, 55, 'cabbage', None], ['Joe', 54, 'MIA', 42, 85, 'cabbage', None], ['Tom', 7, 'LAX-MCO', 4, 52, 'cabbage', None], ['Tom', 4, 'LAX', 43, 52, 'cabbage', None], ['Tom', 4, 'MCO', 4, 5, 'cabbage', None], ['Fred', 4, 'LAG-ITH', 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'], ['Fred', 4, 'LAG', 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'], ['Fred', 4, 'ITH', 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage']]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no replace function for lists. 
Try this:

```
for row in list_of_data:
  if '2tm' in row:
    id = list_of_data.index('2tm')
    next_i = id + 1;
    next_again = id + 2;
    list_of_data[id] = list_of_data[next_i] + '-' + list_of_data[next_again]
```